# How can I avoid to load a function in admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I add below code to my `function.php`, it crashes my admin panel. How do I add this code only if it's **not** admin panel?

```
add_action('init', 'hekim_sticky_header');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using an anonymous function and only call your sticky header if not the admin:

```
add_action('init', function(){
  if (!is_admin()) {
    hekim_sticky_header();
  }
});
```

or the more traditional route:

```
function example_func(){
  if (!is_admin()) {
    hekim_sticky_header();
  }
}
add_action('init', 'example_func');
```